# curl POST format for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, post, curl

When I use `curl` via `POST` and set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELD` do I have to `urlencode` or any special format?

for example: If I want to post 2 fields, first and last:

```
first=John&last=Smith
```

what is the exact code/format that should be used with curl?

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$reply=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 107):

In case you are sending a string, urlencode() it. Otherwise if array, it should be key=>value paired and the `Content-type` header is automatically set to `multipart/form-data`.

Also, you don't have to create extra functions to build the query for your arrays, you already have that:

```
$query = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
```

Comment: You can just use `http_build_query($data)` since `&` is the default separator.

Comment: Of course you can skip them. This is to illustrate the other two arguments that you may (or may not) change (ex. the default separator) to suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 70):

**EDIT**: From php5 upwards, usage of [`http_build_query`](https://php.net/http_build_query) is recommended:

```
string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, 
                          string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )
```

Simple example from the manual:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";

/* output:
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
*/

?>
```

---

***before php5:***

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. **This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.** As of PHP 5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in array form to work.

So something like this should work perfectly (with parameters passed in a associative array):

```
function preparePostFields($array) {
  $params = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $params[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
  }

  return implode('&', $params);
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass a string if you can pass an array...?

Comment: You're right, I'm just somehow used to this because it's the same as GET - a matter of habit so that you won't "forget" to escape next time you're doing GET.

Comment: I think $key should be encoded too, just in case you have it like "name&surname" etc. Especially if data is given by the end user

Comment: @barius, I agree with you. And I think http_build_query() actually is better than the function defined above.

Comment: @skyfree I agree! That function was added in php5 though which was still far from standard in 2011.

Comment: why http_build_query is required when you could just pass array?

Comment: @Offenso - without `http_build_query`, what is sent, for an array, is a *multi-part form*. This may or may not be what you want, but it requires different code at the receiving end.  See [curl examples in PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php#117009) -- Roberto Braga's example "when using curl to post form data and you use an array for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option, the post will be in multipart format". Wrapping array with `http_build_query` instead sends the traditional `key1=value1&key2=value2`.

Answer (score 42):

### Do not pass a string at all!

You can pass an array and let php/curl do the dirty work of encoding etc.

Comment: passing an array will be a different Content-type than a string, so there is a good reason to do so.  Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I find that on my win dev pc passing an array takes about a second longer (1.029s using array vs. 0.016s using `http_build_query()` on that same array)

Comment: Nested arrays won't work. cURL will try to convert them to string and a PHP _Array to string conversion_ notice will follow

Comment: This is a **dangerous** answer in many situations where it isn't just a basic key-based, single dimension array.

Answer (score 16):

## It depends on the `content-type`

### url-encoded or multipart/form-data

To send data the standard way, as a browser would with a form, just **pass an associative array**. As stated by PHP's manual:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

### JSON encoding

Neverthless, when communicating with JSON APIs, content must be JSON encoded for the API to understand our POST data.

In such cases, content must be explicitely encoded as JSON :

```php
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2]),
```

When communicating in JSON, we also usually set `accept` and `content-type` headers accordingly:

```php
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'accept: application/json',
    'content-type: application/json'
]
```

Answer (score 10):

For `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, the parameters can either be passed as a urlencoded string like `para1=val1&para2=val2&..` or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value

Try the following format :

```
$data = json_encode(array(
"first"  => "John",
"last" => "Smith"
));

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hi Shraddha, `json_encode()` will give you something really different of a valid parameter string as `first=John&last=Smith`. `json_encode()` will output: `{"first":"John","last":"Smith"}` which will then become the raw body of your POST request.

Comment: To add to @7ochem's comment:  Unless the recipient is expecting *a single parameter containing a json-encoded string*, instead of `json_encode(...)` do `http_build_query(...)`. This will create the expected "url-encoded string" containing the parameters separated by "&".

Answer (score 9):

One other major difference that is not yet mentioned here is that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can't handle nested arrays.

If we take the nested array `['a' => 1, 'b' => [2, 3, 4]]` then this should be be parameterized as `a=1&b[]=2&b[]=3&b[]=4` (the `[` and `]` will be/should be URL encoded). This will be converted back automatically into a nested array on the other end (assuming here the other end is also PHP).

This will work:

```
var_dump(http_build_query(['a' => 1, 'b' => [2, 3, 4]]));
// output: string(36) "a=1&b%5B0%5D=2&b%5B1%5D=3&b%5B2%5D=4"
```

This won't work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['a' => 1, 'b' => [2, 3, 4]]);
```

This will give you a notice. Code execution will continue and your endpoint will receive parameter `b` as string `"Array"`:

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in ... on line ...

Answer (score 6):

According to the PHP manual, data passed to cURL as a string should be URLencoded.  See the page for [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and search for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 2):

We were looking for the same solution when we wrote a test for CMS Effcore. The solution turned out to be quite simple and it is shown below:

```
$data = [
  'name[0]' => 'value 1',
  'name[1]' => 'value 2',
  'name[2]' => 'value 3',
  'id'      => 'value 4'
];

$data = array(
  'name[0]' => 'value 1',
  'name[1]' => 'value 2',
  'name[2]' => 'value 3',
  'id'      => 'value 4'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly the way [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) does POST is a complete GET operation with these 2 additional options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
```

Just another way, and it works very well.

Comment: Excellent, simple and worked for me aswell!! thank you Klompenrunner!

Answer (score -3):

This answer took me forever to find as well. I discovered that all you have to do is concatenate the URL ('?' after the file name and extension) with the URL-encoded query string. It doesn't even look like you have to set the POST cURL options. See the fake example below:

```
//create URL
$exampleURL = 'http://www.example.com/example.php?';

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init(); 

// build URL-encoded query string
$data = http_build_query(
    array('first' => 'John', 'last' => 'Smith', '&'); // set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $exampleURL . $data); 

// return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources <br/>
curl_close($ch);
```

You can also use `file_get_contents()`:

```
// read entire webpage file into a string
$output = file_get_contents($exampleURL . $data);
```

Comment: It seems like you are doing a GET rather than a POST.