# File is empty when POST a file with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, file, rest, post, curl

I am trying to upload a file using a RESTful web service as follows:

```
$filename = "pathtofile/testfile.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$filecontents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

$data = array('name' => 'testfile.txt', 'file' => $filecontents);

$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_close($client);
```

But I keep gettig ***file is empty*** as a response for this request.

I tried also sending the file path like:

```
$data = array('name' => 'testfile.txt', 'file' => 'pathtofile/testfile.txt');
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

**Or:** just sending the contents of the file only like:

```
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $filecontents);
```

But the same response: ***file is empty***.

**Note that:** the file exists and not empty, and I am just trying to only upload the file no additional fields .

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields) , but the same problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array ('myfile' => '@'.$filename);
```

This will fill `$_FILE ['myfile']` for the receiving end.

Edit: to *actually* put the file contents as the body, you could do it directly:

```
//Get the file data
$body = file_get_contents ($filename);
$len = strlen ($body);

//Open a direct connection to the server on port 80
$socket = fsockopen ('hostname.example.com', 80);

//Write the HTTP request headers
fwrite ($socket, "POST /path/to/url HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite ($socket, "Host: hostname.example.com\r\n");
fwrite ($socket, "Connection: Close\r\n");
fwrite ($socket, "Content-Length: " . $len . "\r\n");

//Empty line marks end of headers, start of body
fwrite ($socket, "\r\n");

//Actually write the body
fwrite ($socket, $body);

//Get the result (half a kB at a time)
$result = '';
while (!feof ($socket)) $result .= fread ($socket, 512);

//Clean up nicely
fclose ($socket);
```

Note that that code is untested, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I have tried it but it seems like the problem is in the service itself, I reviewed their documentation and they said that *the entire request body is saved as a new file* so how would `$data` looks like and what parameters should I pass to the service in this case should it be the contents of the file and the content type only or what? When I just send the contents of the file nothing posted to the service.

Comment: Wow, that is a weird API. Can you post a link to it? If it really does work that way, you may have to skip cURL and do it yourself via a direct socket write, as it doesn't appear cURL for PHP lets you set the POST body directly (accepting only an array or a URL-encoded string).

Comment: Note that they said that: *File should be sent as a binary stream* but I tried it as I said in my question above and it works but the file url gives me: Bad request or malformed parameters, and i checked the server and no file was uploaded or uploaded empty, so could you explain this.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how it can be done using direct socket writes.

Comment: Thanks alot for your responses, I tried it It gives me no errors and no reponses as well I debug it using Firebug but there is no files uploaded, and how can I get the reponse they provided in thier documentation in the form of `file_key` and `file_url`

Comment: The result should be in `$result`. That would include the headers though. To split into headers and body, `list ($headers, $body) = explode ("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);`

Comment: But why I couldn't do that with curl i.e. how to make the entire request body as a new file and make the content type with the file content type. is this possible and why they mention that?

Comment: They designed the API in a very non-standard way. Personally, I'd call it bad design, but maybe they have a good reason for it. (The PHP interface to) cURL doesn't allow it simply because it's been written for the common case, not this weird edge-case. It just doesn't know how to handle it.