# How to POST data to Asana instead of GET?

Tags: php, curl, asana

I'm using cURL in PHP to access the Asana API.

I've been happy appending my values to the URL as GET but now, as my app grows larger, I'm posting more and more data, so I've been trying to convert it to post.

So far, I've tried:

```
setting post['data'] to a json object {key:value,key:value}
setting post['data'] to a json object {options:{key:value,key:value}}
setting post['data'] to a json object {data:{options:{key:value,key:value}}}
setting post['data'] to a json object {data:{key:value,key:value}}
setting post['body'] to all of the above json objects
```

For my methods so far, I end up with the error:

```
Could not parse request data, invalid JSON
```

Using cURL, of course, I'm doing this:

```
$post = json_encode($myFields);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('data'=>$post));
```

For all of these tests, I'm outputting the JSON and validating it with JSLint. It's very valid JSON, so the problem definitely isn't that. I just need to know WHY it's not valid.

I just can't quite get it to work. Thanks for any help- Daniel.

Comment: show your code please to help you more because this is not enough

Comment: Does the information given in this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields

Comment: I'm afraid not- Their solution was to combine it into a GET string, which is exactly what I'm trying to get away from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to encode in JSON all you array, not only the "data" part :

```
$post = json_encode(array('data' => $myFields));
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Comment: Adrien, when setting the CURLOPT postfields, it can take an array of key->value's and use them all as post fields, so `data` is my key, and the value is `json_encode($myFields);`

Comment: Not sure, but the official Asana API docs do seem to put `data` in their JSON-encoded array, which may explain why their API is refusing to process your JSON request: see around line 20 on http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#UseCases

Comment: Daan, I'm afraid I tried that and it didn't work. It just refuses to work for some reason. In the example on the documentation, they assigned that JSON to the `body` property of the net object. I don't know what the equivalent is in PHP.

Comment: "body" is the content of your request.

Comment: How do I set the body in PHP?

Comment: As said by Google : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "body goes here" ); `

Comment: I think that should do it.. I'm still getting errors, but it seems to be going through now. Thanks.

Comment: So whats up with the asana docs showing examples where you post urlencoded data. Those examples don't seem to be sending json, but their apis seem to only accept json. WTH

Answer (score 3):

I made a PHP class wrapper for Asana API. You can grab it here: https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class