# curl api isnt responding anything

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to write PHP code for following API:

```bsh
curl -u ********* -d email=tester@gmail.com \
--data-urlencode msg="First message from domain API" \
--data-urlencode url="http://www.domain.com/welcome" \
https://api.domain.com/1/send
```

#### PHP Code:

```php
<?php
$url = "https://api.domain.com/1/send ";

$ch = curl_init();    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "*********"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=test@outlook.com&msg=hi%url=http://yahoo.com/"); // add POST fields

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

echo $result;       

?>
```

What am I doing wrong to process the above API?

Comment: [How to debug curl requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

Comment: what's the problem?  Are you getting any errors?  Anything value for $result?  It's hard to know what you need without telling us what's wrong.

Comment: By saying "curl api isnt responding anything" you mean that `$result` is `false`? If `$result` is an empty string, you should print out and post here the server's response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode("email=test@outlook.com&msg=hi&url=http://yahoo.com/"));
```

There may be other errors (I can't easily test your code) but that should help. Notice that, in addition to adding the `urlencode` function, I also changed a `%` to a `&`

[This question will probably help you, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Comment: better suggestion is to just put the post fields into an array and let curl do the encoding for you. it'll happily accept an array.

Comment: @durron597 its still not returning anything, do you need complete code to test?

Comment: @seoppc I recommend following my link and following Marc B's advice if you haven't yet.

Comment: @durron597 i have tried that, please find complete api curl code at http://codepad.org/UPiCklPj so you could have a test as well, thanks for your efforts.