# How can I send POST data to a phantomjs script

Tags: javascript, post, phantomjs

I am working with PHP/CURL and would like to send POST data to my phantomjs script, by setting the postfields array below:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFieldArray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is I don't know how to parse a POST request inside the phantomjs script. I am using the webserver module to expose the script.

I suspect https://github.com/benfoxall/phantomjs-webserver-example/blob/master/server.js may have the answer, but I don't know enough javascript to tell whether post variables are  being parsed:

```
var service = server.listen(port, function(request, response) {

if(request.method == 'POST' && request.post.url){
    var url = request.post.url;

    request_page(url, function(properties, imageuri){
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write(JSON.stringify(properties)); 
        response.write("\n");   
        response.write(imageuri);
        response.close();
    })
```

Can someone show me how to parse a POST request here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.post` object contains the body of the POST request. If your `$postFieldArray` is indeed an array, then (at least according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224895/1402935)) PHP should have encoded the array and POSTed it <s>with the content type `x-www-form-urlencoded`</s>. Actually, according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Although it is not explicit in the [API reference](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/), this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10340) suggests that PhantomJS will expose the content of an `x-www-form-urlencoded` form as properties on the `request.post` object. That's what seems to be happening in the example (`request.post.url` refers to the form field `url`). The easiest way to check would be to log the `request.post` object to the console and see what's in there.

However, the GitHub issue also implies that `multipart/form-data` is not supported by the PhantomJS webserver. So, unless you're prepared to change to a different web server, it might be easiest just to encode the data with JSON. On the PHP side:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode(json_encode($postFieldArray)));
```

And then on the PhantomJS side:

```
var data = JSON.parse(request.post);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps my understanding a lot, I'm going to post a follow up question based on my attempts to implement what you discussed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434387/post-parameters-strangely-parsed-inside-phantomjs