# POST parameters strangely parsed inside phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, http, post, phantomjs

I am working with PHP/CURL and would like to send POST data to my phantomjs script, by setting the postfields array below:

In my php controller I have:

```
$data=array('first' => 'John', 'last' => 'Smith');
$url='http://localhost:7788/';
$output = $this->my_model->get_data($url,$data);
```

In my php model I have:

```
public function get_data($url,$postFieldArray) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFieldArray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

In my phantomJS script that I am running locally I have:

```
// import the webserver module, and create a server
var server = require('webserver').create();
var port = require('system').env.PORT || 7788;     

console.log("Start Application");
console.log("Listen port " + port);    


// Create serever and listen port 
server.listen(port, function(request, response) {    

        // Print some information Just for debbug 
        console.log("We got some requset !!!"); 
        console.log("request method: ", request.method);  // request.method POST or GET     

        if(request.method == 'POST' ){
                       console.log("POST params should be next: ");    

                    console.log("POST params: ",request.post);
                    exit;
                }
```

I first start and run the phantomjs script (myscript.js) from the command line, then I run my php script.

The output is:

```
$ phantomjs.exe myscript.js
Start Application
Listen port 7788
null
We got some requset !!!
request method:  POST
POST params should be next:
POST params:  ------------------------------e70d439800f9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first"

John
------------------------------e70d439800f9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last"

Smith
------------------------------e70d439800f9--
```

I'm confused about the the output. I was expecting something more like:

```
first' => 'John', 'last' => 'Smith
```

Can someone explain why it looks this way? How can I parse the request.post object to assign to variables inside myscript.js

Edit:

I've made the changes you have suggested in your answer in [How can I send POST data to a phantomjs script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418277/how-can-i-send-post-data-to-a-phantomjs-script/19418512#19418512).

As you suggested, I changed the php/curl encoding to

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode(json_encode($postFieldArray)));
```

In the phantomjs script, I have:

```
if(request.method == 'POST' ){
                   console.log("POST params should be next: ");
                   console.log(request.headers);
                   var data = JSON.parse(request.post);
                   console.log("POST params: ",data);
```

when I run the script from php I see the following in my console:

```
Start Application
....
POST params should be next:
[object Object]
```

At this point, the script hangs and I cannot see any output in the dev tools browser console . Can you advise me on how to see the contents of the object?

Comment: When you directly log an object without trying to convert it to a string, there would normally be an arrow allowing you to expand and inspect it -- at least in Chrome developer tools, which is what I usually use. If you're a Firefox user, maybe installing Firebug would help.

Comment: I've switched over to the POSTMAN extension to chrome and have had some success please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550582/parsing-post-data-in-phantomjs

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the form is being encoded as `multipart/form-data` rather than `application/x-www-urlencoded`. Apparently PHP does this when the value of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an array. You could check this by adding `console.log(request.headers)` to your debug code.

Unfortunately, it looks like PhantomJS doesn't support `multipart/form-data`. If you're not willing to find another web server, the easiest solution is probably to manually encode the data using JSON. I've fixed the mistake in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418512/1402935) and added some example code.

Comment: Thanks again for your detailed answer Sjy. Please see above for an update. - Bill