# Parsing post data in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am working with the POSTMAN extension to chrome and am trying to send a post request to phantomjs I have managed to send a post request to a phantomjs server script by setting postman as in the attached screenshot[image]

My phantomjs script is as follows:

```
// import the webserver module, and create a server
var server = require('webserver').create();
var port = require('system').env.PORT || 7788;     

console.log("Start Application");
console.log("Listen port " + port);    

// Create serever and listen port 
server.listen(port, function(request, response) {    

      console.log("request method: ", request.method);  // request.method POST or GET     

      if(request.method == 'POST' ){
                       console.log("POST params should be next: ");
                       console.log(request.headers);
                    code = response.statusCode = 200;
                    response.write(code);
                    response.close();

                }
 });
```

when I run phantomjs at the command line , here is the output:

```
$ phantomjs.exe myscript.js
Start Application
Listen port 7788
null
request method:  POST
POST params should be next:
[object Object]
POST params:  1=bill&2=dave
```

So , it does appear to work. My question is now how to parse post body into variables, so I can access it in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read post data, you should not use `request.headers` as it's HTTP headers (encoding, cache, cookies, ...)

As said [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/), you should use `request.post` or `request.postRaw`.

`request.post` is a json object, so you write it into the console. That's why you get `[object Object]`. Try to apply a `JSON.stringify(request.post)` when logging.

As `request.post` is a json object, you can also directly read properties using indexers (do not forget to add a basic check if the property is not posted)

Here is an updated version of your script

```
// import the webserver module, and create a server
var server = require('webserver').create();
var port = require('system').env.PORT || 7788;

console.log("Start Application");
console.log("Listen port " + port);

// Create serever and listen port 
server.listen(port, function (request, response) {

    console.log("request method: ", request.method);  // request.method POST or GET     

    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        console.log("POST params should be next: ");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(request.post));//dump
        console.log(request.post['1']);//key is '1'
        console.log(request.post['2']);//key is '2'
        code = response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write(code);
        response.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. You solved my problem ! I ended up using console.log("POST params: ",JSON.stringify(request.postRaw)); which outputs the following string :"1=bill&2=dave" . Best regards - Bill