# How to access JSON POST data in PHP?

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I'm trying to create a [webhook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) to send JSON encoded data to a users webhook receiver.

This is how I send the data:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/user-webhook-receiver.php';
    $data = array('title' => 'Hello',
    'message' => 'World',
    'url' => 'http://example.com/#check');

    $content = json_encode($data);

    $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                    array("Content-type: application/json"));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

How can the user access the data I sent him?
I tried this, but there is no content in it:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
```

How to access the data?

Comment: Just send the array as it is (this should put it in `$_POST`).

Comment: Not a solution per se, but do yourself a favor and use Requests for PHP instead of curl: https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields) for how you need to encode the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

You need to do something like:

```
$postdata = "content=" . urlencode($content);
```

On the sending side.

Then on the receiving side:

```
$content = $_POST['content']; 
$content = urldecode($content);
$json_content = json_decode($content);
```

Although, I agree with the comment above that you should just send the array. What's the point of JSON encoding it you're POSTING the data?

EDIT: to *just send the array* you would do:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

(but see the question I linked to for more details on how to do it with URL encoding)

On the receiving side, you would do:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: What you mean with _just send the array_? Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

To read raw POST data in php, you can do the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

It's also possible to pass an associative array directly to `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);` - if you do that, PHP will be able to automatically convert it back to an array in `$_POST` on the receiving end.