# Doing a curl request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to do a curl request on a site and I can't seem to get it working.

Here is what I have

```
<?php
 $mynumber = $_GET["mynumber"];
 echo $mynumber;
 $url = 'thewebsite/c/number='.$mynumber; // like this?
 $curl_header = array('X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest');
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "number=$mynumber"); //??? --data     "number=12345678" ?
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result;
 curl_close($ch)
 ?>
```

And here is the curl request:

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" -H "Referer: thewebsite" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "number=12345678" --compressed  POST /thewebsite/c HTTP/1.1
```

I am not sure how to pass "--data "number=12345678"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields

Comment: Put `print curl_error($ch)` just before the `cur_close` call. also you are missing a `;` at the bottom. probably a typo.

Comment: @Bjorn is right, just add all your headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the `--data` parameter correctly. But you forgot to set the `Content-Type`, `Accept`, `Referer` and `Connection` headers. You can add those the way you set the `X-Requested-With` header (in `$curl_header`):

```
<?php

$cookie = '';
$mynumber = $_GET['mynumber'];

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/c/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer: http://example.com/c/',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "number=$mynumber");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```