# POST data and return with CURL as variable (not output)

Tags: php, jquery, curl

My task is to post selected autocomplete value from `index.php` to `test.php`.I need to return data to `index.php` as a variable not an output.I think I need to use `php CURL`.But I don't get any  positive result yet.

index.php:

```
select: function(event, ui)
      {
selected=ui.item.value;

    jQuery.ajax({

url:"test.php",
data:{selected},
type:"POST",

success:function(data){

}
</script>

<?php

if(isset($response)){

echo $response;
}
```

test.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["selected"])){

    $selection1=$_POST["selected"];

    $url=mysite.com/index.php";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $selection1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}

?>
```

Comment: why do an http request to your own site? php's already running as par tof that site. and your test.php doesn't actually output anything. you run curl, then simply exit. you should at least have `echo $response` or somethingo, so the curl results get sent back to the JS code.

Comment: ok, but with `echo` i wll back only output?I need back actual variable with an value

Comment: I assume that test.php is POSTing to another domain or, as @MarcB points out, this would not be needed. What di you get in $response? have you checked that $_POST values are as expected? Have you tried encoding $selection1? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields for more info on encoding the curl POST

Comment: So I gues this line should be like this: `$url="index.php?";` 
and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($selection1));`