# Append $msgArray to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

Is it possible to assign `$msgArray` as a last element of the array which is used in curl

```
foreach( $attachmentsArray as $att )
    {
        $msgArray["attachment[$x]"] = curl_file_create( $att );
        $x ++;
    }
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'from' => 'Open <test@gmail.com>',
  'to' => $email,
  'subject' => $subject,
  'html' => $msg
));
```

Comment: [useful information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just as a pump, does this work for you?

```
foreach( $attachmentsArray as $att )
    {
        $msgArray["attachment[$x]"] = curl_file_create( $att );
        $x ++;
    }

$arrayValues = array(
  'from' => 'Open <test@gmail.com>',
  'to' => $email,
  'subject' => $subject,
  'html' => $msg,
  'attachments' => http_build_query($msgArray)

  /** or an alternative form of collapsing an array into a
     string value, such as json_encode($msgArray);  **/
);


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrayValues);
```

[reference](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) (recommended)