# curl instead of file_get_contents with context

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

i would like to replace file_get_contents with curl (sipgate voip account) , but every tryout does not work.

Version mit file_get_contents:

```
    $requestParameter = array(
    'RemoteUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $remoteUri),
    'LocalUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $localUri),
    'TOS' => 'voice'
);
    $auth = base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("samurai.SessionInitiate", $requestParameter);
    $context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => sprintf("Content-Type: text/xml\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s)", $auth),
        'content' => $request
    ))
);
    file_get_contents("https://api.sipgate.net/RPC2", false, $context);
```

Latest Tryouts with curl

```
    $requestParameter = array(
    'RemoteUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $remoteUri),
    'LocalUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $localUri),
    'TOS' => 'voice'
);
    $auth = base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("samurai.SessionInitiate", $requestParameter);
    $context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => sprintf("Content-Type: text/xml\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s)", $auth),
        'content' => $request
    ))
);
    $url = 'https://api.sipgate.net/RPC2';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $context);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

AND

```
    $requestParameter = array(
    'RemoteUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $remoteUri),
    'LocalUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $localUri),
    'TOS' => 'voice'
);
    $auth = base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("samurai.SessionInitiate", $requestParameter);

    $url = 'https://api.sipgate.net/RPC2';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Has someone an idea for me?
Thx, spf

Comment: What is in the PHP error log?

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts URL query format. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields .

Comment: Unfortunately, my error log is empty. Maybe the log of the URL has entries, but i didn't know.

Comment: I tried the first version with http_build_query(), and now error log has an entry: PHP Warning:  http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object.

Answer (score 0):

The above named error on both versions

```
$requestParameter = array(
'RemoteUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $remoteUri),
'LocalUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $localUri),
'TOS' => 'voice'
);
$auth = base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("samurai.SessionInitiate", $requestParameter);
$context = stream_context_create(
array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => sprintf("Content-Type: text/xml\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s)", $auth),
    'content' => $request
    ))
);
$data = http_build_query($context);
$url = 'https://api.sipgate.net/RPC2';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

and

```
$requestParameter = array(
'RemoteUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $remoteUri),
'LocalUri' => sprintf('sip:%s@sipgate.de', $localUri),
'TOS' => 'voice'
);
$auth = base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("samurai.SessionInitiate", $requestParameter);

$data = http_build_query($request);
$url = 'https://api.sipgate.net/RPC2';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```