# Passing value in postfield. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl

this is my parameter i want to pass in  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

```
{"user":{"user_id":"346"}}
```

example :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {"user":{"user_id":"346"}});
```

how i can do it ?

thanks

Comment: By handing it over as valid string (which appears to be json encoded): `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"user":{"user_id":"346"}}');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl POST format for CURLOPT\_POSTFIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example your data is `json` so You need to pass data as `json string`

```
$data_string = '{"user":{"user_id":"346"}}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

Also when you pass json, set header as json application

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```

Comment: don't set the Content-Length header manually, curl will do it for you automatically. and unlike you, curl won't make any typos

Comment: btw, if you'd like to encode it from native php data, it's `json_encode(array('user'=>array('user_id'=>346)))`