# Array to String Conversion - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am seeing nothing wrong in my code below. However, when i run in my browswer, i get the error `array to string conversion`. What could i be missing in my code.

The error points to this line of code `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Thank you for your help

```
    $url = 'example.com/2394'
    $curlFile = curl_file_create($file);
    $data = [

       'msg_code' => '',
       'time' => ''
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
```

Comment: `http_build_query($data)` is what you need. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` expects a `* char` parameter for the data, IE: `foo=bar&bar=foo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl POST format for CURLOPT\_POSTFIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Comment: But from the docs regarding CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, `this parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. ` So an array, should be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS requires an urlencoded string or an array as param. Read [PHP Manual curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php). Have changed your example, now it uses an urlencoded string.

change that code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: Although this is correct, please refrain from answering duplicate questions that already have answers. This makes the original poster think to ask more off-topic questions in the future without researching prior.

Comment: @Jaquarh yea sorry, I didn't see comments. but why downvote ?

Comment: @ttrasn Not my downvote, but answers on duplicate questions can be considered "not useful", which is probably what the downvote is for. The question already has a near identical answer to yours on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields - there is no reason to have such a similar answer to the same question in a different place