# Use PHP Variable inside PHP string

Tags: php

I am learning PHP. I have two variable like this

```
$user_name = 'abc';
$pass = '12345';
```

I want use it inside curl string which originally require like this

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "username_or_email": "abc",
    "password": "12345"
    
}',
```

I am trying like below

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"username_or_email": '.'"$user_name"'.',"password":'.' "Freelance12"'.'}'
```

but its not working. Anyone can please help me for solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields) would be a good starting point. You don't have to build it manually.

Comment: `'{"username_or_email": "' . $user_name . '"'`. Or : `json_encode(["username_or_email" => $user_name, "password" => "Freelance12" ])`

Comment: If the post fields are supposed to be in json, then you should build up an array and use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) to create a properly formatted json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl POST format for CURLOPT\_POSTFIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"username_or_email": "'.$user_name.'","password": "Freelance12"}'
```

I dont know why you try to concat the main string with Freelance12; Freelance12 is a string, you can write directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would probably be the approach I would recommend. Your POSTFIELDS looks like JSON so I would let PHP do the heavy lifting of turning it into a valid JSON object.

```php
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    'username_or_email' => $user_name, 
    'password' => $pass
])
```

All this does is create an associative array and then JSON encode it with the aptly named `json_encode()` function.

Were you to print the JSON string that is returned from this `json_encode()` call it would be...

```
'{"username_or_email": "abc", "password": "12345"}'
```