# Curl post file PHP Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php

Please tell me how to transfer a file using curl post without php warning that $ data_curl is an array `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion...`

```
$data_curl = array('domain' => $domain, 'token' => '*', 'files' => array());
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $file) {
   $tmpfile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $filename = $name_file."_".time().".".$type;
   $data_curl = $data_curl + array(
      'file'.$i => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $_FILES['files']['type'][$i], $filename)
   );
   $i++;    
} 
$ch = curl_init('https://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_curl);
curl_exec($ch);
```

`json_encode` and `http_build_query` do not send file.

Comment: Change `content-type` to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Learned something new then. If only we had the ACTUAL error message instead of a cropped one

Comment: @hppycoder I agree. The OP needs to show on which line the error is coming and what's inside those inputs from the user.

Comment: @hppycoder error in this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_curl);`

Comment: @Vector Did the header change fix the issue?

Comment: So it's similar to this post then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields

Comment: @hppycoder If you might have noticed, I also send files. These are not the same questions.

Comment: @nice_dev I changed it, the warning remained.

Comment: If you didn't notice the first answer with 100+ votes says: `In case you are sending a string, urlencode() it. Otherwise if array, it should be key=>value paired and the Content-type header is automatically set to multipart/form-data.` which is what @nice_dev has bene saying. Remove the Content-Type all together and send the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why error pops up is because you have

```
$data_curl = array('files' => array());
```

The values cannot be arrays in themselves and rather just a string or an integer or floats or booleans with an exception of `CURLFile` objects .

Also, there is no point in sending `files` key as a POST param with no value inside it. So you could better remove it completely and just keep `$data_curl = array();`

Comment: How then can I pass some variables in the array?

Comment: @Vector Can you edit your post with an example?

Comment: @Vector Why do you still need `'files' => array()` at the end?

Comment: Without 'files' => array () at the end works without warnings. Thanks! The question is closed.