# why my CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data is not passed to the server?

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, php-curl

i make a simple api which return some value but if i add this line and pass data like `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $data);` my api return null here is the complete code

```
  $data = ['a' => "data"];

        $url = env('MOTHERSHIP_URL') . '/store/cstore/receipt';
        Log::debug("url=" . $url);
        $cURLConnection = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $data);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                    
        $apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
        curl_close($cURLConnection);
        $data = json_decode($apiResponse, true);

        dd($data);
```

route

```
Route::any('/store/cstore/receipt', 'CStoreController@StoreCstoreReceipt')->name('store.cstore.receipt');
```

controller

```
public function StoreCstoreReceipt(Request $request){

         Log::debug($request->all());
        return "Success";
     }
```

**problem is if i add `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $data);` api return null if dont add this line then it works fine what i am doing wrong? i also tried an other method but in this i am getting some html accept of getting response**

Comment: Apply http_build_query() to $data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields

Comment: try to pass data in url

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($arr));`