# Unable to POST data TO REST API Using PHP CURL but it work fine with Postman

Tags: php, rest, postman, php-curl

I am trying to post a data to REST API using PHP/CURL and seems it's not working, as i get 301 Moved Permanently error,But it works fine with Postman. Here is the snippet of PHP CURL which i generated form Postman

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'api url',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('text' => 'test'),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'api_key: key',
'Content-Type:application/json',
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

And it always return 301 Moved permanently, Note if i change the API key i got Unauthorised error, which means it hits the server, but i am not sure what i am missing, I have tried with multiple headers combinations.

Any help on this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try by sending data like this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "text=test&text2=test2");`

Comment: @TarangP Still getting the same.

Comment: Answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the PHP manual :

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded
> string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field
> name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the
> Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

Since you use **array** you'll need to use **multipart**.

See this post : [curl POST format for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields)

Comment: ,I am testing it, but seems it's not working

Comment: The 301 error is a bit weird. Are you sure the URL is correct and doesn't automatically redirect to another?

Comment: Yes. It works fine with Postman. If you want i can share you the collection

Comment: Postman is probably doing something different, you'll need to understand what it is...