# PHP code return different curl result than expected

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl  which I converted to PHP code. When I tested the PHP code, the result is different from curl command

the curl :

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/developer-portal/invoices/reporting/single' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: en' \
  -H 'Clearance-Status: 0' \
  -H 'Accept-Version: V2' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "invoiceHash": "PEx8bNFcEMEpHzUVvQntQI6ot8eFqTT/l59b+H1HqX4=",
  "uuid": "16e78469-64af-406d-9cfd-895e724198f0",
  "invoice": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLT"
}'
```

I tested the above with https://reqbin.com/curl

the Status I got was, Status:401 (Unauthorized)

with PHP I got the Status : 400 ( Bad error ).

here is the PHP code I wrote

```
<?php
$url = "https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/developer-portal/invoices/reporting/single";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   'Clearance-Status: 0' , 
   'Accept-Version: V2' , 
   'accept-language: en' , 
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = [

  "invoiceHash" => "PEx8bNFcEMEpHzUVvQntQI6ot8eFqTT/l59b+H1HqX4=",
  "uuid" => "16e78469-64af-406d-9cfd-895e724198f0",
  "invoice"=> "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLT",
];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump ($resp);

curl_close($curl);

 ?>
```

I tried test the php code on https://reqbin.com/code/php, I got the same result as my machine ( 400 Bad error ).

after the comment, I modified my php code to :

```
<?php
$url = "https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/developer-portal/invoices/reporting/single";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   'Clearance-Status: 0' , 
   'Accept-Version: V2' , 
   'accept-language: en' , 
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$data = array("invoiceHash" => "PEx8bNFcEMEpHzUVvQntQI6ot8eFqTT/l59b+H1HqX4=", 
"uuid" => "16e78469-64af-406d-9cfd-895e724198f0" , 
"invoice" => "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLT");

$data =  json_encode($data);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump ($resp);

curl_close($curl);


?>
```

I still got different result : ( string(0) "" ).

Comment: What about json_encode your request body in PHP code?

Comment: In the PHP version you didn't encode the $data as JSON before sending it, but in the original cURL, it's JSON. That would explain why you got "400 Bad Request" - if the server doesn't recognise or accept the format of data you sent to it - and not only that, the format you've sent doesn't match the Content-Type header you provided. (And PHP Curl will [automatically set the header to multipart/form-data format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224940/5947043) for the request, if you provide an array into the POSTFIELDS.)

Comment: I added :  $data = array("invoiceHash" => "PEx8bNFcEMEpHzUVvQntQI6ot8eFqTT/l59b+H1HqX4=", 
"uuid" => "16e78469-64af-406d-9cfd-895e724198f0" , 
"invoice" => "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLT");

$data =  json_encode($data); I still got different result

Comment: Ok. And what different result was that, specifically?

Comment: ( string(0) "" )

Comment: OK. Have you checked whether curl_error returns anything? Or checked what the http response headers look like?

Comment: No curl error. the http respone headers : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2024 15:17:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 13
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the result from _your_ webserver, in response to the HTTP request to your PHP script? Did you follow a process such as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) to get the headers returned from the cURL request? I just want to double-check we're talking about the right thing.

Comment: Thanks mate. the link in your last comment has the Solution.